# Installation of wine32 in a docker container

Tags: apt, wine, docker, official-repositories

I'm trying to get a Windows application to run in a Ubuntu docker container. When installing wine32 I get the following errors (I'm on a Windows 10 PC):

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxcb/libxcb1_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb  Undetermined Error [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libieee1284/libieee1284-3_0.2.11-13_i386.deb  Undetermined Error [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I already tried out several fixes and (this is where it gets really headach-inducing) some of them actually fixed the issue but then it popped up again:

- First of all I followed the links in the error messages and made sure they exist
- I tried the fixes suggested in the error message as well as the --no-cache flag I read about but both didn't help.
- I used the --network=host flag, which did fix the issue for one build, but then it came back
- I added the DNS server of my company to deamon.json, which fixed the issue for another run, but then it came back yet again

**Edit**: Putting *apt-get upgrade* in the dockerfile fixed it for another single run. In this one run, it seemed to only pull 201 packages instead of the usual 230, which was fortunate, as 202 is the first that usually fails.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /app

COPY Debug.7z ./
COPY dist.7z ./

RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install wine32 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install p7zip

RUN 7zr x -oDebug Debug.7z
RUN 7zr x -oDebug dist.7z

CMD ["wine", "Debug/File.exe"]
```

Command:

```
docker build --network=host --no-cache -t file.linux:test .
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Undetermined error` and the fact that the OP tried to download from an Ubuntu server, rather than from a PPA repository, are common to my situation. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and no containers. In my case I was fetching packages from a national download server, and switching to the main server sorted out the issue.

[image]

**In other words, the undetermined error was some remote problem under the hood of the download server**. I have documented this solution in https://askubuntu.com/a/1216074/446253 too